# Map constructor utility class in Java 8

Tags: java, performance, hash-map

In a Java 8 project, I'm using several maps, many of which contain static or default content. In Java 9 and newer, there's the convenient [`Map.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of--) method and I want something similar convenient. So, I came up with the following implementation:

```
public class CollectionUtils {

    private static final String INCOMPATIBLE_TYPE_MSG_TMP = "The %sth argument is not compatible with the %s type %s";

    /**
     * Shortcut to create a map
     * @param keyClass      type class of keys
     * @param valueClass    type class of values
     * @param keysAndValues array with keys and values (even indices: keys, odd indices: values)
     * @param <KeyT>        type of keys
     * @param <ValueT>      type of values
     * @return unmodifiable map
     */
    public static <KeyT, ValueT> Map<KeyT, ValueT> map(
            Class<KeyT> keyClass,
            Class<ValueT> valueClass,
            Object... keysAndValues) {
        if (keysAndValues.length % 2 != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number of keys and values must be even");
        }
        Map<KeyT, ValueT> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
        KeyT key = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < keysAndValues.length; i++) {
            Object keyOrValue = keysAndValues[i];
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                if (!keyClass.isInstance(keyOrValue)) {
                    String message = String.format(INCOMPATIBLE_TYPE_MSG_TMP, i, "key", keyClass.getName());
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
                }
                key = keyClass.cast(keyOrValue);
            } else {
                ValueT value;
                try {
                    value = valueClass.cast(keyOrValue);
                } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                    String message = String.format(INCOMPATIBLE_TYPE_MSG_TMP, i, "value", valueClass.getName());
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(message, e);
                }
                outputMap.put(key, value);
            }
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(outputMap);
    }
}
```

I did quite a lot of tinkering to get this implementation and I believe there's still room for improvement. For example, the first two arguments must be the key and value classes to get the types correctly, which Java 9's `Map.of()` doesn't require. Besides implementational improvements, I'm also open to comments regarding efficiency, security and anything sub-optimal with this implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why you sould want to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when the error case is actually a literal `ClassCastException`. This is actually counterproductive as you are hiding the fact that the error was caused by class incompatibility and replacing it with a generic illegal argument exception. For example, the `java.util.List.remove(Object)` throws a `ClassCastException` if you feed it the wrong type of objects.

Since you know that the length of the array is divisible by two, you can pick both key and value from it at the same time without having to track the state the loop is in, and advance the loop counter by 2.

The loop becomes quite simple now:

```
Map<KeyT, ValueT> outputMap = new HashMap<>(keysAndValues.length / 2);
for (int i = 0; i < keysAndValues.length; i += 2) {
    outputMap.put(
        keyClass.cast(keysAndValues[i]),
        valueClass.cast(keysAndValues[i + 1]));
}
```

Is your code actually a performance bottle neck? There is not much one can do to make converting an array to map much faster. Giving the `HashMap` it's initial size to perevent it from doing unnecessary rehashings is one thing.

Comment: Wow, the code becomes so much simpler now, thank you! I mainly use this code in static areas, such as to initialize static class members, not really performance critical. But I was hoping someone would catch any language- or runtime-specific problems in my approach, which puts forward my understanding of the language.

Comment: @Green绿色 If absolute performance is not a critical requirement, you should look into the builder pattern: https://minborgsjavapot.blogspot.com/2014/12/java-8-initializing-maps-in-smartest-way.html . This seems like a case where a builder is actually useful. They're a bit more cumbersome to use than pure Object arrays, but they provide compile time type checking.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I haven't thought about applying the Builder pattern to this problem, but from a usage perspective, the Builder approach looks much better than mine.

Comment: The use of `new HashMap<>(keysAndValues.length / 2)` will still cause a resize, because it fails to take into account the default loadfactor of 0.75.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Good point. It's a bit silly desing from the API developers as it works differently than, say, ArrayList initial capacity.

Comment: Yes, and they introduced the static methods [`HashMap.newHashMap(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#newHashMap(int)) in Java 19 to actually do what you'd expect that constructor to do (for backwards compatibility reasons, they don't change what the constructor does).

Answer (score 3):

Not a fan of hacking compile-time type-safety, so I'm just going to mention an alternative.

`Pair` class is a classic, you can find it in most libraries like `apache-commons` or even in `JDK` in a way (`Map.Entry`), wrote it here just to demonstrate.

```java
public class Pair<K, V> {
    public K key;
    public V value;

    public Pair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static <K, V> Pair<K, V> of(K key, V value) {
        return new Pair<>(key, value);
    }
}

public class CollectionUtils {
    public static <KeyT, ValueT> Map<KeyT, ValueT> map(Pair<KeyT, ValueT>... input) {
        Map<KeyT, ValueT> outputMap = new HashMap<>(input.length);
        for (Pair<KeyT, ValueT> pair : input)
            outputMap.put(pair.key, pair.value);
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(outputMap);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = CollectionUtils.map(
            Pair.of("a", 1),
            Pair.of("c", 2)
    );
    
    System.out.println(map);
}
```